# Excel IF and AND with three outputs

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm trying to get Excel to produce three different text outputs depending on the following conditions

```
if E60<100 and (B9-E41)<E36 and E31> or equal to B9 then display "Yes"
if (E31<B9) then display "D limits range"
if E41> or = to B9 then display "L not limiting range"
```

I have tried the following but get an error highlighting the B9

```
=IF(AND(E60<100,(B9-E41)<E36,E31>=B9),"Yes",IF(E31<B9),"D limits range",IF(E41>=B9),"L not limiting DF range")
```

Can't see what the problem is unfortunately

I guess that each of the text outputs is based on a "if you see this, display this". Problem is there isn't a "what to do if none of these are true?

Any suggestions most welcome

Comment: The immediate problem is the closing brackets after the last two B9s. These three scenarios do not appear to be necessarily mutually exclusive?

Comment: Thank you! That has fixed it. I'm double checking the logic flow of the conditions now to be sure

Comment: The formula I changed it to, which works is: =IF(AND(E60<100,(E41-B9)<=E36,E31>=B9),"Yes",IF(E31<B9,"D limits range",IF(E41>=B9,"L not limiting range")))

Comment: You can post your formula as an answer, and I'm not sure but you might be able to accept it too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing some brackets

```
=IF(AND(E60<100,(B9-E41)<E36,E31>=B9),"Yes",(IF(E31<B9),"D limits range",(IF(E41>=B9),"L not limiting DF range","something else"))))
```

Comment: `=IF(AND(E60<100,(B9-E41)<E36,E31>=B9),"Yes",IF(E31<B9,"D limits range",(IF(E41>=B9,"L not limiting DF range","something else"))))`